# Difference between "be of great importance" or "have great importance"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference in meaning between that two phrases? 
Example:

> A change request is a document containing a call for an adjustment of a system; **it is of great importance** in the change management process. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_request)

Example 2:

> Exclusive: IAEA chief: Nuclear summit **has great importance** [cctv](http://english.cctv.com/2016/03/31/VIDEI4vsvA3Xi2U88FAuovsq160331.shtml)

Comment: There's little difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, there is little or no difference in meaning.  However, there may be a nuance.  "Be" means to possess intrinsically.  "Have great importance" could imply a qualifier, have great importance to a specific set of people but perhaps not others, more a sense of importance in the eyes of the beholder than an intrinsic quality.

Answer (score 0):

> Definition of 'be of' in English:
>
> PHRASE
>
> Possess intrinsically

To be of something is the same thing as to have something.

Comment: But to “have something” is **not** the same as to be of something.    “He has problems” is not the same as “he is of problems”, which is nonsensical.